# Running on external Spark 3.0.1 cluster from IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark3

I have recently upgraded to Spark 3.0.1 from 2.4.6 (and scala 2.11.12 to scala 2.12.10). I write and execute applications from IntelliJ Idea and in the past was able to run with both the Master set to local[*] or remotely using spark://xx:7077. My typical method of running remotely was to also submit the fat jar generated by the artefact functionality available within IntelliJ.

Since the upgrade, I am for some reason unable to run remotely. What could the reason for this be?

**SparkContext settings**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master(projectionConfigOptions("Master"))
            .appName(projectionConfigOptions("AppName"))
            .config("spark.jars", "C:\\PathToJar\\ProjectLife.jar")
```

**Standard error output**

```
Spark Executor Command: "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.272.10-hotspot\\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\bin\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..\conf\;C:\bin\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=57603" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@DOMAIN:57603" "--executor-id" "5" "--hostname" "192.168.1.139" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20201028134035-0001" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.1.139:57251"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/10/28 13:50:52 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 14388@DOMAIN
20/10/28 13:50:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/10/28 13:50:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: tjoha
20/10/28 13:50:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: tjoha
20/10/28 13:50:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/10/28 13:50:53 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/10/28 13:50:53 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(tjoha); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(tjoha); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/10/28 13:50:54 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to DOMAIN/192.168.1.139:57603 after 640 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
20/10/28 13:50:55 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from DOMAIN/192.168.1.139:57603
java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3456489343829468865, local class serialVersionUID = 1028182004549731694
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1850)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2160)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$deserialize$2(NettyRpcEnv.scala:292)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$deserialize$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:291)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$askAbortable$7(NettyRpcEnv.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$askAbortable$7$adapted(NettyRpcEnv.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcOutboxMessage.onSuccess(Outbox.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:142)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$1(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help to bridge this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, any insights so far?

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes i think this is related to a spark version conflict between your local and the cluster
you should provided dependency on the same version of Spark as is on your cluster